# Type of "this" inside coroutine

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I have function:

```
fun buttonClick(view: View){
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch{ //this:CoroutineScope 
    Log.i(TAG,"${this.javaClass.toString()}")
    while (this.isActive) {
    //...
                }
         }
    }
```

In Logcat I see: `class kotlinx.coroutines.StandaloneCoroutine`. But if I step inside `while (this.isActive)` while debugging, I see call of `CoroutineScope.isActive` - not a call of StandaloneCoroutine (or AbstractCoroutine) method. i.e. "this" have  CoroutineScope type- not StandaloneCoroutine. Could anyone explain this behavior of "this"?

Answer (score 2):

When you inspect your code in the IDE, `this` is only known to be a CoroutineScope in the context of the code around it. The compiler only knows `this` to be a CoroutineScope, because that is the type defined in `launch()`. The actual instance of CoroutineScope in this case happens to be a StandaloneCoroutine instance which implements the interface of CoroutineScope. StandaloneCoroutine is a private implementation detail that you can only inspect at runtime using reflection (like you did by using `javaclass`).

Answer (score 2):

`StandaloneCoroutine` is a subtype of all of these: `Job`, `JobSupport`, `Continuation` and `CoroutineScope`.

On the other hand, `isActive` is an extension property on `CoroutineScope`. Extension properties/functions do not belong to types, that is their fundamental characteristic. It doesn't matter which implementation of `CoroutineScope` you have, the implementation of the extension property is always the one and only `public val CoroutineScope.isActive: Boolean`, and the IDE took you there.

You may have been thrown off by the fact that this extension property is declared in the file `CoroutineScope.kt`, but if you check carefully, you'll see it's as top-level declaration and it's not inside the `CoroutineScope` interface (which is just a one-liner).